# How do i render html string from component.ts file into component.html file Angular 6?

Tags: json, angular6

- I have a code where i have retrieved json data from a url and am
  currently trying to load the data from the contact.component.ts file
  to contact.component.html file. Now i have already created a
  EscapeHtmlFile and tried to render my data accordingly but not
  getting the required result.

  I have added DomSanitizer as suggested by some tutorials but none fit my issue.

  ```
  import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
  import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

  @Pipe({ name: 'keepHtml', pure: false })
  export class EscapeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {
   constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
   }

   transform(content) {
     return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(content);
   }
  }   


  import { Component, OnInit, Pipe } from '@angular/core';
  import { Http } from '@angular/http';

  @Component({
   selector: 'app-contacts',
   templateUrl: './contacts.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./contacts.component.css']
  })
  @Pipe({name: 'keepHtml'})
  export class ContactsComponent implements OnInit {
   private contactsUrl = 'https://public-  api.wordpress.com/rest/v1.1/sites/vocon-it.com/posts';

   constructor(http: Http) {
     http.get(this.contactsUrl).subscribe(result => {
       this.posts = result.json().posts;
     }, error => console.error(error));    
    }

   ngOnInit() {
     // this.getContacts();
   }

   posts: string[];

   data_template = '<div class="overview-box"><img src="{{post.author.profile_URL}}" class="img-thumbnail" alt="">'
   +'<h2>{{post.author.first_name}}</h2><hr><p>{{post.author.email}}</p><p>{{post.author.nice_name}}</p>'
   +'<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> &nbsp;Read More</a></div>';

  }
  ```

  i expect the actual output to render the data as the value from {{post.author.first_name}} but i keep on getting the same output as
  but not the value.

Edit - Code Formatting.

Comment: Format ur question pls

Comment: Show html file please

Comment: <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div *ngFor="let post of posts" class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12 mab-30">
      <div class="overview-box">
        <img src="{{post.author.profile_URL}}" class="img-thumbnail" alt="">
        <h2>{{post.author.first_name}}</h2>
        <hr>
        <p>{{post.author.email}}</p>
        <p>{{post.author.nice_name}}</p>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> &nbsp;Read More</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

Comment: Where do you use 'data_template'?

Comment: i use it in my contacts.component.html file, i simply try to access it normally as we do but i do not get the value but simply retrieve string with {{ }} brackets on it